# Decomposition of integral non-generate matrices

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $GL_{\eta}(n,\mathbb{Z})=\left\{a\in
>  GL(n,\mathbb{R})\cap M^{n\times n}(\mathbb{Z})|det(a)=\eta\right\}$. Prove that there exists a
>   finite number of matrices $a_i$ in $GL_{\eta}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ such that
>   any matrix $a\in GL_{\eta}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ can be written as
>   $a=a_i\alpha$, where $\alpha \in SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$

Could someone give me some ideas or references for that fact? Thank you so much!

Comment: The only options for $\eta$ are $\pm1$, so $a_1=\operatorname{diag}(-1,1,\ldots,1)$ should suffice.

Comment: Here I mean $\eta$ is an arbitrary integer number, not only $\pm 1$

Comment: But the defintion of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is the set of $n \times n$ matrices whose determinant is a unit.

Comment: @JeremyRouse Maybe the OP means $GL(n, \mathbb{R}) \cap M^{n \times n}(\mathbb{Z}).$

Comment: @IgorRivin But again, $\operatorname{diag}(\eta,1,\ldots,1)$ works.

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky No, it does not, because then $\alpha \notin SL(n, \mathbb{Z}),$ at least not obviously.

Comment: I don't understand the "close" votes - the question is confused, but does contain an interesting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic words are *Hermite Normal Form*. If you read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form), you will discover that the magic matrix $H$ is upper-triangular, with every off-diagonal element *smaller* than the (maximum, for the sake of argument) diagonal element. Since the product of the diagonal elements is equal to $\eta,$ their maximum is at most $\eta,$ and that means that there are finitely many (at most something like $(2\eta)^{n(n+1)/2}$) possibilities.

Comment: Believe it or not, there is a (relatively) closed form for the number of Hermite equivalence classes with determinant $d$: it is $\phi * J_2 * \dots * J_{n-1}(d)$ where $\phi$ is the usual Euler totient, $J_k$ are the successive Jordan totients, and * denotes number theoretic-convolution. For square-free $d$, it's not so bad to compute with. Let the OP figure out the proof (by induction).

Comment: oops, I'm working with GL(n,Z), not SL(n,Z); for the latter, there is an extra factor of 2.

Comment: Sorry---the formula I gave above is for the number of Hermite equivalence classes of matrices of size $n$ with determinant $d$ and *all columns unimodular* (with which I've been working recently), for $n\geq 2$; without the unimodular constraint, I think it's $\sigma * \phi * J_2* \dots* J_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 3$. This is what happens when I comment when I'm tired.